# Wamp Server error on running wordpress theme on localhost. How do I fix this error?

Tags: theme-development

I am getting an error while running a wordpress theme on wamp server. This error does not appear when I use the default theme but when I run it using a custom theme I getting an error. This custom theme is from one of the tutorial that I am taking. The codes in the respective files which I followed from the tutorials and the error are shown below
Error:
[image: error]
index.php:
[image: index]
header.php:
[image: header]
footer.php:
[image: footer]

I saved this new custom theme inside the C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes as explained in the tutorial. How do I fix this error. I am unable to learn visually as I can't see how codes are working.

Comment: This is not a question about Wordpress, but a syntax question on PHP. The error message tells you exactly where the error is (line 7 on `index.php`). You need a closing `?>` tag after `the_post()`. You are also missing a trailing semicolon on line 13 in the same file. Please try to debug your code first before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It be better if you have paste the code and not images but here you go:

Correct in `index.php`

```
<?php 
get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <h2>....
```

Adding some context to above, the error telling that it found a character that doesn't belong in that position. `line 7` **<** h2.
This is why You add the closing php tag above. `the_post(); ?>`